# Is Lenovo ideapad 330 IKB the same as IKBR? And should I update the BIOS to my 330 IKB?

Tags: windows-10, bios, bsod, lenovo-laptop, lenovo-vantage

I have Lenovo Ideapad 330 15 IKB, with Windows 10 (I7-8550U). Lenovo vantage says that I have a BIOS update. (8TCN55WW). 
Buy it says that the update is for 15 IKBR only. Is it the same as the 15 IKB?

And if it's the same, should I do this update? Because last time I updated the BIOS, after that - whenever I tried to close Android Studio's emulator - I got BSOD, and also when I played Fortnite, I sometimes got BSOD. (Both of them where DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE, it think). 
But this BIOS update says that what it does it: "Fix system  sometimes occur BSOD when  playing games".

But due to what happened last time I updated the BIOS, I'm worried. I will happy for some recommendations.

Thank's!

Comment: No. It has a different CPU.

Comment: So why did I get this update to my machine?

Comment: "the update is for 15 IKBR only" so don't install it.

Comment: Where did you find this update?

Comment: On Lenovo Vantage...